# Get user city from location coords data, in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got the coords but cannot get it to show the city. I almost got it. I even got the API key it requires but cannot do anything more. Please help me, I am going nuts. If you have any other way that I could do it, you can show it aswell it would be appreciated. Thank you. Here's what I could do so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, PermissionsAndroid, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import GetLocation from 'react-native-get-location'

const locationToAdress = async(location) => 
    {
    const locationPublish = `${location.latitude},${location.longitude}`; //PUBLISH
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${locationPublish}&sensor=true&key=${config.myGoogleAPIisaSecretnumber}`;
    fetch(url)
    .then((result) => {
    const { results } = result;
    console.log(results);
    
    })
    .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    });
    }

  const requestLokasyonPermission = async () => {
   
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          timeout: 15000,
        })
        .then(location => {
          console.log(location);
          console.log(location.latitude);
          console.log("lokasyon seysi bu" + location.longitude);
          locationToAdress(location);
        
        
        })
        .catch(error => {
          const { code, message } = error;
          console.warn(code, message);
        })
      );
      
  };

const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
        message:
          "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
          "so you can take awesome pictures.",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera");
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.item}>Try permissions</Text>
    <Button title="request permissions" onPress={
  () => { requestCameraPermission();}
 }/>
    <Text style={styles.item}>Try permissions</Text>
    <Button title="request permissions" onPress={
  () => { requestLokasyonPermission();}
 }/>
  </View>
  
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8
  },
  item: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: check the response of about url in browser. You are using wrong API key

Comment: OK I enabled it, it sends my city data but now how to show that in my phone? I can't do it. I tried results[4] or something, it gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

In `locationToAdress` you have used `geocode` service which converts address to latitude and longitude. In your case, you want the opposide - i.e. from latitude and longitude coordinates to address for which one should use `reverse geocoding` service as given [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse#maps_geocoding_reverse-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on react-native-get-location, but you can refer below example for your code.
I am using react-native-geolocation-service.
Remove ${config.} before API Key

P.S. : Never Post Your Google Map API Key directly on any site.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, PermissionsAndroid, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service'

const locationToAdress = async (location) => {
    const locationPublish = `${location.latitude},${location.longitude}`; //PUBLISH
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${locationPublish}&sensor=true&key=YOURGOOGLEMAPAPIKEY`;
    fetch(url)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
}

const requestLokasyonPermission = async () => {

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                    title: "Location Permission",
                    message:
                        "This App needs access to your location " +
                        "so we can know where you are.",
                }
            );
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                console.log("You can use locations ");
            } else {
                console.log("Location permission denied");
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    }
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (location) => {
            console.log(location);
            locationToAdress(location.coords)
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
};

const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
            {
                title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
                message:
                    "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
                    "so you can take awesome pictures.",
                buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
                buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                buttonPositive: "OK"
            }
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("You can use the camera");
        } else {
            console.log("Camera permission denied");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }
};

const App = () => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.item}>Try permissions</Text>
        <Button title="request permissions" onPress={
            () => { requestCameraPermission(); }
        } />
        <Text style={styles.item}>Try permissions</Text>
        <Button title="request permissions" onPress={
            () => { requestLokasyonPermission(); }
        } />
    </View>

);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
        backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
        padding: 8
    },
    item: {
        margin: 24,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center"
    }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: That almost works! One little thing, it brings loads of data back, I only need city and province data. How can I just show that? In the website, its under result named as 3 and 4. I think they are like arrays, so I tried results[4] or something but it didn't work :( Please one last help.